# poster with two logos on LHS and RHS

Tags: posters

I have a poster template and want to have two logos at the top LHS and RHS corners of the frame.
So here's the title section:

```
{\sf\bf Unnecessarily Complicated \\ Research Title} % Poster title
{\vspace{1em} John Smith, James Smith, Jane Smith\\ % Author names
{\smaller j.smith@uni.edu, j.smith2@uni.edu, j.smith3@uni.edu}} % Author email addresses
{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{logo}} % University/lab logo
```

And when I add the following line to the beginning of the title section:

```
{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{logo}} % University/lab logo
```

The result is an out-of-boundary mess ! I even put the `eyecatcher=true` in the `\begin{poster}{}` section, yet it has no effect on it ! I wonder if you help 
Thanks

Comment: by the way, I am using this template: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/baposter-portrait-poster

Answer (score 2):

The `\begin{poster}` command has a second argument that is the left column and can be used for such a logo.  It is the `{}` just before the comment "TITLE AND AUTHOR NAME" in the sample tex file.  Here is an example using that argument in the standard sample document, see the line with the comment `%%%Added left logo`.  I have scaled down the logo's a bit more so that is enough space.

[image: Sample output]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% baposter Portrait Poster
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (15/5/13)
%
% Created by:
% Brian Amberg (baposter@brian-amberg.de)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{relsize} % Used for making text smaller in some places

\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\definecolor{bordercol}{RGB}{40,40,40} % Border color of content boxes
\definecolor{headercol1}{RGB}{186,215,230} % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
\definecolor{headercol2}{RGB}{80,80,80} % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
\definecolor{headerfontcol}{RGB}{0,0,0} % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{186,215,230} % Background color for the content in the content boxes

\begin{document}

\background{ % Set the background to an image (background.pdf)
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw (current page.north west)+(-2em,2em) node[anchor=north west]
{\includegraphics[height=1.1\textheight]{background}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{poster}{
grid=false,
borderColor=bordercol, % Border color of content boxes
headerColorOne=headercol1, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=headercol2, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=headerfontcol, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=boxcolor, % Background color for the content in the content boxes
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers
headerfont=\Large\sf\bf, % Font modifiers for the text in the content box headers
textborder=rectangle,
background=user,
headerborder=open, % Change to closed for a line under the content box headers
boxshade=plain
}
{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo}}  %%%Added left logo
%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE AND AUTHOR NAME
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
{\sf\bf Unnecessarily Complicated \\ Research Title} % Poster title
{\vspace{1em} John Smith, James Smith, Jane Smith\\ % Author names
{\smaller j.smith@uni.edu, j.smith2@uni.edu, j.smith3@uni.edu}} % Author email addresses
{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo}} % University/lab logo

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,row=0}{

Donec feugiat sagittis \textbf{neque}, nec ultrices risus vestibulum at. Suspendisse enim purus, tempus sed malesuada et, aliquam non nulla. Cras vel tortor justo. Vestibulum viverra purus id risus lacinia quis malesuada lorem mattis. \textbf{Nullam ornare egestas} metus vel posuere. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In malesuada aliquet nulla, quis iaculis mauris accumsan ac.

Maecenas placerat hendrerit mollis. Nunc fringilla sollicitudin pulvinar. Vestibulum a odio arcu. \textit{Ut tristique enim ut odio pulvinar non dignissim risus dignissim.} Nullam nibh augue.
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MATERIALS AND METHODS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Materials and Methods}{name=methods,column=0,below=introduction}{

\begin{description}
\item[ER1] Sed a orci non ipsum posuere placerat. Nunc in mi augue, a adipiscing massa. Donec dapibus gravida odio, condimentum convallis urna.\item[ER2] Nullam sagittis cursus neque, sit amet mollis elit auctor in. Etiam sed lectus a nulla rhoncus interdum a tempus nunc. Sed at eleifend purus.
\end{description}

Nullam sollicitudin lobortis urna quis varius. Nullam sagittis blandit diam, $DN = G_t(V_t,E_t)$, risus $E_t \subseteq V_t \times V_t$ ($\forall t \geq 0$). vel tortor justo, $G_0$, quis malesuada lorem.

\begin{equation}
\cos^3 \theta =\frac{1}{4}\cos\theta+\frac{3}{4}\cos 3\theta
\label{eq:refname}
\end{equation}

Vivamus porta lacus et lectus \textbf{porta lacus}. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. torte $G_t$ hac millis \textbf{plates} Idk 
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONCLUSION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Conclusion}{name=conclusion,column=0,below=methods}{

Fusce at erat vitae metus porttitor auctor sit amet at ante. In id dolor tellus, non aliquet elit. Vestibulum bibendum, augue sed laoreet congue, enim nisi ultricies diam, ac pharetra mi dui ut sapien. Maecenas fermentum, neque ut scelerisque consequat, purus leo ultrices nulla, quis scelerisque risus elit non turpis. 

\begin{enumerate}
\item Cras ac ipsum eu nisl imperdiet interdum nunc bibendum, est in pulvinar facilisis, mi purus fringilla tellus, eu varius ipsum ante laoreet ipsum
\item Sed cursus erat quis odio laoreet facilisis maecenas vehicula
\end{enumerate}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{References}{name=references,column=0,below=conclusion}{

\smaller % Reduce the font size in this block
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em} % Get rid of the default "References" section title
\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sample} % Use sample.bib as the bibliography file
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Acknowledgements}{name=acknowledgements,column=0,below=references, above=bottom}{

\smaller % Reduce the font size in this block
Fusce mattis tellus ac odio imperdiet lobortis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus commodo blandit euismod. Ut porttitor cursus magna. Mauris adipiscing pellentesque ipsum nec facilisis. Cras ornare bibendum bibendum. Ut a elit purus, vel adipiscing.
} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESULTS 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Results Heading}{name=results1,span=2,column=1,row=0}{ % To reduce this block to 1 column width, remove 'span=2'

Nunc sit amet sem ut nulla tincidunt mattis vel nec mauris. Vestibulum odio tellus, lobortis. Vel adipiscing, Aliquam dictum, ligula egestas commodo posuere, lectus lectus congue ligula, sed posuere urna lectus at nisi. Aenean commodo risus ut dolor (viverra scelerisque). Nullam varius, lacus et interdum hendrerit, odio orci ultrices mauris, id interdum eros mauris at urna. Fusce in nisi eros, sit amet volutpat turpis, \textbf{porttior magna} (commodo blandit euismod) \textbf{facilisis ornate magnis} (dis magnis). 

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Treatments} & \textbf{Response 1} & \textbf{Response 2}\\
\midrule
Treatment 1 & 0.0003262 & 0.562 \\
Treatment 2 & 0.0015681 & 0.910 \\
Treatment 3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table caption}
\end{center}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESULTS 2
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Results Heading 2}{name=results2,span=2,column=1,below=results1,above=bottom}{ % To reduce this block to 1 column width, remove 'span=2'

Nunc sit amet sem ut nulla tincidunt mattis vel nec mauris. Vestibulum odio tellus, lobortis. Vel adipiscing, Aliquam dictum, ligula egestas commodo posuere, lectus lectus congue ligula, sed posuere urna lectus at nisi. Aenean commodo risus ut dolor (viverra scelerisque). Nullam varius, lacus et interdum hendrerit, odio orci ultrices mauris, id interdum eros mauris at urna. Fusce in nisi eros, sit amet volutpat turpis, \textbf{porttior magna} (commodo blandit euismod) \textbf{facilisis ornate magnis} (dis magnis). 

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{placeholder}
\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{placeholder}
\captionof{figure}{Figure caption 1 (left); Figure caption 2 (right)}
\end{center}

%------------------------------------------------

Aliquam ac justo lectus. Nunc ultrices aliquet purus non dictum. Nulla facilisi. Quisque vitae urna non purus sollicitudin venenatis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In hendrerit tortor sed massa consequat eu viverra justo porta. Ut nec felis sem, non elementum.

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{placeholder}
\captionof{figure}{Figure caption}
\end{center}

%------------------------------------------------

Nunc sit amet sem ut nulla tincidunt mattis vel nec mauris. Vestibulum odio tellus, lobortis. Vel adipiscing, Aliquam dictum, ligula egestas commodo posuere, lectus lectus congue ligula, sed posuere urna lectus at nisi. Aenean commodo risus ut dolor (viverra scelerisque). Nullam varius, lacus et interdum hendrerit, odio orci ultrices mauris, id interdum eros mauris at urna. Fusce in nisi eros, sit amet volutpat turpis, \textbf{porttior magna} (commodo blandit euismod) \textbf{facilisis ornate magnis} (dis magnis). Aliquam ac justo lectus. Nunc ultrices aliquet purus non dictum. Nulla facilisi. Quisque vitae urna non purus sollicitudin venenatis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In hendrerit tortor sed massa consequat eu viverra justo porta. Ut nec felis sem, non elementum.
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```